# Add modules to my Angular App Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

How can I load my modules(selected based on user after logged in) in my Angular app dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading modules in Angular is not a trivial task but can be done.
Here is a very good article regarding this topic:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150513130815/http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/

The related code can be fount on [GitHub: ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

Comment: Fixed the link, but you really need to summarise the content here (in your own words) to make your answer useful.